# Upgrade scenario from 4.6C to ECC 6.0

Tags: sap-erp, sap-basis, sap-r3

I have next two servers:

- Solaris 8, Oracle 8.1.7, SAP 46C
  installed and working for production
- Solaris 10, Oracle 10 with NO SAP but
  with 40% more of the capacity than
  previous server

I will install and configure SAP ECC 6.0 in ServerTo and will transfer all data from 46C. Under this scenario I would like to know if the next generic steps are valid:

1. Homogeneous copy of SAP 46C using r3copy
2. Begin installation of SAP ECC 6.0
3. In some phase of the installation, I
   expect SAP asks for the copy
   generated in step 1.
4. Continue with the installation, I am
   supposing that ECC 6.0 will be able
   to recognize that the copy files
   generated in step 1 correspond to
   SAP 46C version and will import data
   transparently.
5. I configure SAP ECC 6.0 and apply
   last patches.
6. At the end, I will have two
   productive SAPs in different
   versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** You comment( if I read it correctly) sounds like a working solution. Here are, what I think, the usual steps. You should do them first on a test system. Just to put some perspective. We did this upgrade recently ( from 4.6c to ecc6) during the project we did something between 10 to 15 upgrades on testing, integration an training systems.

1. install sap 4.6 with oracle 8.1.7 on the target server.
2. copy ( backup and restore ) the database from the source system.
3. Upgrade the database to Oracle 10. Read sap documentation on this process. Some updates will be needed for the sap kernel (brconnect...) and db roles.
4. Run the sap upgrade process. Read the mountain of documentation before you begin.

**Before update:** I think that you are to optimistic. The sap upgrade process is anything but simple.

About your steps:

1. I didn't use r3copy, but I think that it can be used only with same os/db. Maybe the solaris 8 is similar enogh to 10. But the db version will surely prevent the use of r3copy.
   2 to 4. The installation process does not recognize previous installations! You can have many instances of sap on the same host and user. So it doesn't care.
   5 and 6. Not relevant.

Comment: Igal, and what if the first step is distributed in the next way?
1.1) Homogeneous DB copy of SAP 46C
1.2) I install SAP 46C on Solaris10 with the option to import copy of 1.1
1.3) Check if the installation was ok.
1.4) I begin the upgrade to ECC 6.0 in the Solaris10. Steps 3 and 4 does not apply.
?